# Go over json data in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
$jsondata = '{
    "ips":  {
                "10.20.30.40":  [
                                       {
                                           "rhost":  "DNS Name1.",
                                           "rdata":  [
                                                         "10.20.30.40"
                                                     ],
                                           "rrtype":  "A (1)",
                                           "ttl":  86400,
                                           "geo":  null,
                                           "source":  "DNSProvider1"
                                       }
                                   ],
                "40.50.60.70":  [
                                       {
                                           "rhost":  "DNS Name2.",
                                           "rdata":  [
                                                         "40.50.60.70"
                                                     ],
                                           "rrtype":  "A (1)",
                                           "ttl":  86400,
                                           "geo":  null,
                                           "source":  "DNSProvider1"
                                       }
                                   ]
            }
}'
```

I want to get all the TTLs (for example) of every IP address in the list.

I converted this JSON to Powershell PSCustomObject:

```
$obj = $jsondata | convertFrom-Json
```

and now I want to get all the TTLs, I tried to get the list of the IPs  (as a start):

```
foreach ($ip in $a.ips) {write-host $ip }
```

and I'm not getting strings as a result, that's why I (probably) can't go inside and get the TTLs.

So my question: how can I get all the IPs as strings?

I believe that once I'll get an answer for that, I'll understand how I can go over all the IPs in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps that's a daft remark, but you're not using the same variable between both your examples: `$obj`and `$a`. Is that a typo? Can you show what results you're getting?

Comment: $obj.ips not $a.ips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($ip in $obj.ips | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
{
    Write-Host -Verbose ("IP Address {0} has TTL {1}" -f $ip.Name, $obj.ips."$($ip.Name)".ttl)
}
```

`Get-Member` will get you the name of the property (which is the ip address) and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rubanov, that really helped!

And just to document the whole answer:

```
    foreach($ip in $obj.ips | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
        {
             Write-Host -Verbose $obj.ips.$($ip.Name).ttl
        }
```

Or:

```
($obj.ips | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | % {$obj.ips.$_.ttl}
```